# Deleting folders using rm -rf does not free up space

Tags: macos, bash, mac, rm

I am trying to re-install macOS on my iMac.

My iMac worked perfectly, before I upgraded macOS Ventura (It was a minor upgrade, I was already on Ventura). After I did a regular update, I logged into my user, but every time I logged in the Mac would restart, ask for my password in a weird gray screen, and then I logged into my user, and again and again.

I was advised on the internet to reinstall macOS, so I went to recovery mode and tried to reinstall.

I don't have enough space to reinstall, so I went to the command line in macOS recovery mode (Bash) and removed many large folders and applications with `rm -rf`, including Xcode and Xcode beta.

But the free space remained unchanged. I tried deleting more folders, and verified their size before deleting using `du`, but still after deleting the free space remained unchanged.

I also checked, and after removing, the folders I deleted are no longer there.

I was wondering what can I do next? I don't want to erase my macOS hard drive because I have important project files there. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have Time Machine enabled?

Comment: Perhaps back up the files and then erase.

Comment: I don't have Time Machine enabled @DanielB

Comment: Can I back them up from bash? @John

Comment: I believe so bu I am not certain. Perhaps a Mac user can answer

Comment: What OS are you on & precisely which iMac? Which volume are you checking for free space [bearing in mind the OS & data volumes are artificially summed to the user] Why not just throw things in the Trash then empty Trash? Also, re-installing any modern macOS is truly pointless unless you are going to completely nuke & pave. The system volume is signed & sealed, there's nothing you can do to it, it's inviolable.

Comment: @Tetsujin as said I'm in macOS, but I'm stuck in recovery mode and I need to reinstall macOS. I'm checking for the free space using the Disk Utility to determine how much free space I have, and it seems like its using the ifree column of the "df" command on /Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data. This is also where I deleted folders from using the 'rm -rf' command.

Comment: ***Which*** macOS? 'Macintosh HD - Data' would suggest something between Catalina & Monterey. What is telling you you don't have enough room to reinstall? Are you trying to install to the Data volume by mistake?

Comment: @Tetsujin Please take a look at the question now, I added the full backstory

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204156 to identify which screen you are seeing [&links to help]. You still haven't told us which iMac. Things are a lot different for Apple Silicon than Intel as regards recovery options.

Comment: did you log out/reboot/close the process holding the file? Because if the file is still opened then it'll only be actually deleted when the file handle is closed. Unix allows you to remove the file while it's still opened

Comment: It's starting to sound like filesystem corruption. Try running a disk first aid pass (using the `diskutil` command or the "Disk Utility" app).

Comment: @phuclv I tried restarting my Mac, but still the free size remained unchanged